# Applying vertical-align to two divs using inline-block

Tags: html, vertical-alignment, css

So I have some DIVs.
The structure is this

```
    <div id="content">
        <div id="lcol">some content</div>
        <div id="lcol">some<br />content</div>
    </div>
```

And my problem is that the two divs are of different height. I'm using `display:inline-block` for 'lcol' while 'content' is just a regular div. The two lcol divs do indeed show up side by side, but they are anchored at the bottom of the div. I would like them to be aligned to the top of the div. I tried adding `vertical-align:top` to 'content' but nothing happened.

Any ideas?

JsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/qxe8h/1/

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Give **vertical-align:top** to your **inline-block** elements. Write like this:

```
#lcol {vertical-align:top;}
```

Check this http://jsfiddle.net/qxe8h/2/

Comment: You should only be using an ID once in the DOM. If you're going to have multiple elements that require the same styling, use classes instead.